libcrypto-3.dll error when building in Debug with OpenSSL C++
If I build Release in MT with OpenSSL, everything works fine, but if I build in MTd, then without the OpenSSL dll in the directory I get an error.
enter image description here
Here are the project settings:
enter image description here
enter image description here
Same problem here, but I don't understand what build we're talking about if I use the files from the OpenSSL installer

please tell me what is the 'OpenSSL installer' you mentioned, try to give me a name or url plz and make sure you have the debug version libcrypto-3..dll file(which you need to build the Debug versions from the source).

https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html,
I used libcrypto.lib and libssl.lib from the MTd folder in the Debug assembly

I've utilized the resources provided on the website, and similarly to your approach, I've built the Release in MTd. Despite ensuring the correct configuration of OpenSSL, I'm encountering an error stating: 'cannot open input file 'libcrypto.lib'.' It may be beneficial to consider using a different OpenSSL source.
